# image change in ImageView when its clicked

Tags: android, imageview, instagram

I have created a `ButtonBarLayout` with 5 `ImageView` inside it, I want to change image when it's clicked and focused, just like Instagram.

**P.S** I even used `selector.xml` as below, but it doesn't work

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_active"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_normal"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I want something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L7uC.png), but not [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa4TN.png).

and my conclusion was like this, this looks simple but what if 5? Is there any other simple way to create something like this with only a litle code.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imga:
            ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_white);
            ivB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_b_black);
            ivC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_c_black);
            break;
        case R.id.imgb:
            ivB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_b.white);
            ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_black);
            ivC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_c_black);
            break;
        case R.id.imgc:
            ivC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_c_whtie);
            ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_black);
            ivB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_b_black);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest just change image in `onClick` of the image

Comment: @AbdulKawee i know it works, but when i click the other image, the first image doesn't return to normal image before its clicked. public void onClick(View v){switch (v.getId()){ case R.id.iv1; iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_active)}}; like this.

Comment: you only want to change image when its clicked, and when user is not clicking it stays to normal?? is that ??

Comment: @AbdulKawee yes, change image when its clicked and focused in that image, its like intagram you know

Comment: Check the answer below I have shared, it is exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**btn_selector.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_image" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_image" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normalImage"></item>

</selector>
```

Now to your Button

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
```

I don't get it why this isn't working for you, but here is another way of doing it. Suppose you have 3 imageButtons ,img1, img2, img3. Now `onClick` of imagebutton do this

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_white); 
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
                img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
             }
        });
```

And then on 2nd button

```
img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_white); 
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
                img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i hope i can make bottom bar like instagram, its working but when i clicked the other image, the first image i clicked doesn't return to normal image, its like instagram you know and i use ImageView not button

Comment: but its not focused, i imagin like tablayout, when icon fragment "A" was clicked then the page "A" is open and the icon was change too. and if i click icon fragment "B" then the page "B" is open and the icon was change and icon fragment "A" is back to normal

Comment: This should be working and if its not working then there is and alternative way, simple on click of button A, change image of button A, and also the images of all the buttons to default, on click of B, change b image and replace all other buttons to default image

Comment: public void onClick(View v){
 switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.imga:
   ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_white);
   break;
  case R.id.imgb:
   ivB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_b.white);
   ivA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_a_black);
   break;
  ...
 }
}  **like this one**

Comment: I have edited the answer, kindly check it, and if solved your problem do accept and rate it, so it may help others in future.

Comment: thank you, i appreciate it, and its same like my conclusion above

Answer (score 0):

You are setting drawable in bitmaps, i don't know whether they works with it or not but i do this as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_not_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_default"/>
</selector>
```

Also apply this selector to `background` property of `ImageView` else there will be some space left at borders.

Comment: its working when clicked, but when i click other imge, the image i clicked before is doesn't change to normal image before its clicked

Comment: you should define `state_selected` and `state_pressed` and provide a default drawable at last.

Comment: ohhk you need to state what drawable it should show when it is pressed and when it is not.

Comment: its already change beefore i clicked, i upload the image, please see the white icon not the red one

Comment: try the selector by assigning it to src property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_active" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_focus" />
   <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_focus" />
</selector>
```

Comment: its working when clicked, but when i click other imge, the image i clicked before is doesn't change to normal image before its clicked.

Comment: not like that, please see the correct and the wrong image i upload :), thank you